# a finite induction question from burton's elementary number theory

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, induction

this question comes from burton's elementary number theory, 4th edition.

question 3 in 1.1 says to use the second principle of finite induction to establish that

$$for\ all\ n\ge1,\ ^{(a)}\ a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1)$$

$[hint;\ ^{(b)}\ a^{n+1}-1=(a+1)(a^n-1)-a(a^{n-1}-1).]$

my question comes from the solution manual, where in the first step of induction, where they demonstrate the proposition is true for $n=1$, $^{(a)}$ becomes $a-1=a-1$, and so it must be shown that the proposition stands after $n=k$.
now when $n=1$, clearly $a^n-1=a-1\iff\ n=1$.
further, $(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1)=(a-1)$ identically when $(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1)=1$

so to show that $(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1+1)=1$

this is my work so far;

$$a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1=\sum_{i=1}^{\inf}a^{n-i}=a^n\sum^{\inf}_{i=1}a^{-i},\ when\ n=1\  \Rightarrow\ a^n\sum_{i=1}^{\inf}a^{-i}=a\sum^{\inf}_{i=1}a^{-i}$$

which requires that $$^{(c)}\ \sum_{i=1}^{\inf}a^{-i}=a^{-1}$$

so $$a\sum_{i=1}^{\inf}a^{-i}=a(a^{-1})=1$$

verifying the 1st step in induction...

and that is my question, proving $^{(c)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you need to do a bit of work on thoroughly understanding induction.  To prove
$$a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1)\tag{$*$}$$
for $n\ge1$ you need to do two things:

- prove that if $n=1$ then $(*)$ is true;
- prove that if $(*)$ is true for $1,2,\ldots,n$, then it is true for $n+1$.

The first step is easy, as long as you look carefully at what the second factor means when $n=1$.  In this case the first term is $a^0=1$ and the last term is $1$.  These are actually the same term, so the "in between terms" are not really there, the first and last are just one term, and the factor is just $1$.  So in this case, $(*)$ reads
$$a^1-1=(a-1)(1)$$
which is clearly true.

Now assume that $(*)$ is true for $1,2,\ldots,n$, and use the hint you were given:
$$a^{n+1}-1=(a+1)(a^n-1)-a(a^{n-1}-1)\ .$$
Since we have assumed that $(*)$ is true for $n$ and $n-1$, we have
$$\eqalign{
  a^n-1&=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1)\cr
  a^{n-1}-1&=(a-1)(a^{n-2}+a^{n-3}+...+a+1)\ ;\cr}$$
substituting these into the "hint" equation gives
$$\eqalign{a^{n+1}-1&=(a+1)(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1)\cr
  &\qquad\qquad\qquad{}-a(a-1)(a^{n-2}+a^{n-3}+...+a+1)\cr
  &=\cdots\cr
  &=(a-1)(a^n+a^{n-1}+\cdots+a+1)\cr}$$
and so $(*)$ is true for $n+1$.  By induction, $(*)$ is true for all $n\ge1$.

See if you can finish this by supplying the small amount of algebra I have omitted.

Comment: ok, thank you.  but to be clear i want to express that it is not the induction that i was concerned about not to say that i am great at induction, but rather that what i am confused about is working with the series to show that $a^{n-1}+a^{n_2}+...+a+1=1$, when $n=1$.

Comment: OK fair enough, hope that point has been cleared up.

Comment: when we say that $\sum^{\inf}_{x=1}a^{n-x}=1$ when $n=1$, are we not saying that the infinite series sums to 1 in the first iteration of n interations?  i mean to say that the series is a function of $x$, that exist $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: the reason i ask is because if the series is a function of x, defined for all integers, then when we are concerned for the single case where $n=1$, is there still not an infinite series being summed?  if so, as i am trying to understand, would there not still be an infinite series of terms to be summed, and then the first and the last would not the the only existing terms?

Comment: im sure of it that i am wrong but i am only trying to project clearly what it is that i am actually confused over.

Comment: The point is that when we write the sum $a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a+1$ we mean that you have to add the term $a^{n-1}$ and then all similar terms with decreasing powers until you get to $a^0=1$.  Now if $n=1$ then you start with $a^0$, you are at the end already, so that's all there is, just $1$.

Comment: ...or to put it another way, how many terms are there in $a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a+1$?  I hope it's easy to see that there are $n$ terms.  So if $n=1$there is just one term and it has to be $1$ because that's the term that is always there.